# Retrieve Request instance in eloquent model scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a Session table where I create sessions for users by authenticating in a REST API.

A Session has a relation with a User, so I can retrieve the User object from the Session.

I want to create a Eloquent scope to retrieve the currentUser logged in like `Session::currentUser()->id` where the Authorization header equals the token in the Session table.

It seems I can't use the Request instance in my `scopeCurrentUser()`. Can't inject it via the Controller as well like this:

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Also tried to inject it into the method (which is possible since Laravel 5)

```
public function scopeCurrentUser($query, Request $request)
{
    return $query->where('token', $request->header('Authorization'));
}
```

Any way I can get the `$request->header('Authorization')`?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the request instance by using `app('Illuminate\Http\Request')` or `Request::` (make sure you have `use Request;` at the top of you file).

So either you have

```
use Request;

public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
{
    return $query->where('token', Request::header('Authorization'));
}
```

or

```
public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
{
    return $query->where('token', app('Illuminate\Http\Request')->header('Authorization'));
}
```

You can't do dependency injection in Eloquent methods as far as I know (at least it didn't work when I tried it).